# How to have only one login for multiple websites on the same linux machine?

Tags: linux, active-directory, web-server, single-sign-on

I'm having multiple websites (like mediawiki, gitea and kanboard) and I'm thinking about making the login the same on all services.

But how do I do that?

I looked at AD but I read that it's Windows only?
I also heard about "FreeIPA" but I read that it's used for linux client machines?
Google is sadly not really helping me with that, as the question is too broad to get good results.

All I want is to make the logins on all my websites the same, so that if I create a user (or change password) once it gets updated on every website/service.
I don't necessarily need the client OS (example: windows login) to be involved, but if that is necessary then I will do that.

Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The different web apps will need to support a common authentication backend.  Check what authentication methods/plugins each of them support.  If they are just using an internal database then syncing would require some programming effort.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having multiple websites (like mediawiki, gitea and kanboard) and I'm thinking about making the login the same on all services.

[MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth), [Gitea](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/oauth2-provider/), and [Kanboard](https://github.com/kanboard/plugin-oauth2) supports OAuth2, so you may use that. You may need to implement OAuth2 provider though, such as [ORY/Hydra](https://www.ory.sh/hydra/) or [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/).

> I looked at AD but I read that it's Windows only?

You can communicate to AD with [LDAP](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Microsoft%20Active%20Directory), but you may need to check if your websites support LDAP.

> I also heard about "FreeIPA" but I read that it's used for linux client machines?

Also [uses LDAP](https://www.freeipa.org/page/HowTo/LDAP).

> Google is sadly not really helping me with that, as the question is too broad to get good results.

Try [this](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=Single%20Sign%20On).

Answer (score 0):

You can have only 1 credentials for all websitss which are hosted in same LAN this process is call single -sing -ON this can be accomplished by integrating Active directory . For example when your are trying to login into websit the request should call on active directory to get it done coding has be developed at application server